# Why is my smooth scroll broken when putting an id in a link?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I'm using a smooth scroll script and a js script called animated modal. My scroll script stops working after I press the modal that triggers the animatedmodal.js . 
Any idea why the smooth scroll stops working?

*When I take out the 'id' in the link so the animated modal function doesnt work, the smooth scroll starts working.

The smooth scroll is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var $target = $(this.hash);
      $target = $target.length && $target
      || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if ($target.length) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $('html,body')
        .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 600);
       return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And the link to open the animated modal is:

```
 <li class="active"><a id="contactModal" href="#animatedModal">
```

The div tag of the modal is:

```
<div id="animatedModal">
```

And the script called for the animated modal is:

```
 $("#contactModal").animatedModal();
```

Comment: I just realized it works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: I know it's an old one but it my help someone else. I have fixed mine by restoring the html and body overflow setting after closing the modal: `             $("#contactModal").animatedModal({
                afterClose: function(){
                    $('body, html').css({'overflow':'initial'});
                }
            });`